# Link symfony entities with a not primary keys value

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I am mapping a database that already exists with doctrine, but this has been designed done poorly in the first place:

```
|--------------|    |----------------------|
|  Entity A    |    |  Entity B            |
|--------------|    |----------------------|
|ID   (Int)(PK)|    |ID           (Int)(PK)|
|FOO  (Str)    |    |BAR -> A.FOO (Str)    |
|--------------|    |----------------------|
```

The B entity has stored A.FOO in the database, and not A.ID.
So if the entity A changes A.FOO, this wouldn't cascade to the B entity. So I know this is pretty much horrible, but I wont be able to change their structure currently..

Is there a way to map with doctrine anyway like this ? Seems like I can't because A.FOO is not primary key ?

```
IN B ENTITY
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\A")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="BAR", referencedColumnName="FOO")
 */
```

So in the end i'd like to have a form for my B entity, with a ChoiceType containing the A.FOO values. Do I have to make custom form with an **OptionsResolver** fetching the values, or there more simple direct way with doctrine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys.
>   Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading
>   proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine
>   can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this
>   settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.

(from https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html).

I.e. I don't think that there is any way how to create this association with the annotations & have automatic reference key validation (or cascading definitions). So that would leave you with the non-ideal situation from the schema point of view where you have just two non-connected string columns in two tables - which would basically mean that you will need to handle more things than just the form processing & validation somehow manually: like checks when deleting B instances, fetching the 'connected' entities based on the string values etc.

So the bottom line as I understand it: there is no way how to manage this 'simply' by using doctrine. The simple solution would be to refactor the database structure but if that wasn't an option for you, then I'm afraid that you will have quite some work to do to get this connection working similarly as simple doctrine connections do.

Comment: All right, thanks for the intel :). As I though this is bad ^^. I guess i'll probably have to work a lot to make it work.. properly ?! haha. Thanks anyway